# Converting long integers to strings in pandas (to avoid scientific notation)

Tags: python, pandas, long-integer

I want the following records (currently displaying as 3.200000e+18 but actually (hopefully) each a different long integer), created using [pd.read_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html), to be interpreted differently:

```
ipdb> self.after['class_parent_ref']
class_id
3200000000000515954    3.200000e+18
3200000000000515951             NaN
3200000000000515952             NaN
3200000000000515953             NaN
3200000000000515955    3.200000e+18
3200000000000515956    3.200000e+18
Name: class_parent_ref, dtype: float64
```

Currently, they seem to 'come out' as scientifically notated strings:

```
ipdb> self.after['class_parent_ref'].iloc[0]
3.2000000000005161e+18
```

Worse, though, it's not clear to me that the number has been read correctly from my .xlsx file:

```
ipdb> self.after['class_parent_ref'].iloc[0] -3.2e+18
516096.0
```

**The number in Excel (the data source) is 3200000000000515952**.

This is not about the display, which I know I can change [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results). It's about keeping the underlying data in the same form it was in when read (so that if/when I write it back to Excel, it'll look the same and so that if I use the data, it'll look like it did in Excel and not Xe+Y). I would definitely accept a string if I could count on it being a string representation of the correct number.

You may notice that the number I *want* to see is in fact (incidentally) one of the labels. Pandas correctly read those in as strings (perhaps because Excel treated them as strings?) unlike this number which I entered. (Actually though, even when I enter ="3200000000000515952" into the cell in question before redoing the read, I get the same result described above.)

How can I get 3200000000000515952 out of the dataframe? I'm wondering if pandas has a limitation with long integers, but [the only thing I've found on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550940/python-pandas-insert-long-integer) is 1) a little dated, and 2) doesn't look like the same thing I'm facing.

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that you have floats, not integers. And the number you have too big to have such a precision as a float. The reason you end up with floats is because of the `NaN` values (`NaN` is not supported in integer columns, therefore it is cast to floats).

Comment: Thanks, @joris. Using the keep_default_na=False kwarg of read_excel() seems to have solved the problem. Feel free to answer accordingly and I'll 'check' it.

Comment: @HaPsantran you might just want to provide your own answer as joris seems not to have noticed your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your column values with `NaN` into 0 then typcast that column as integer to do so.

```
df[['class_parent_ref']] = df[['class_parent_ref']].fillna(value = 0)
df['class_parent_ref'] = df['class_parent_ref'].astype(int)
```

Or in reading your file, specify `keep_default_na = False` for `pd.read_excel()` and `na_filter = False` for `pd.read_csv()`