# Pandas convert float in scientific notation to string

Tags: python, pandas

I used `read_csv()` to load a dataset that looks like this

```
userid
NaN
1.091178e+11
1.137856e+11
```

I want to convert the user ids to string. One solution is to add `keep_default_na=False` to `read_csv()`, which is suggested by this SO: [Converting long integers to strings in pandas (to avoid scientific notation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596101/converting-long-integers-to-strings-in-pandas-to-avoid-scientific-notation)

Let's say I don't want to use `keep_default_na=False`. Is there any way to convert the user id column to str.

I tried `df.userid.astype(str)` and I got `1.091178e+11` back. I was expecting the result in the expanded form not scientific form.

What should I do？

Comment: Is possible use parameter `dtype={'userid':str}` and it works for you?

Comment: You could apply a string format `df.userid.apply(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) or `apply`, as mentioned in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157981/pandas-convert-float-in-scientific-notation-to-string/41158287#comment69517471_41157981):

```
print (df.userid.map(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x)))
0             nan
1    109117800000
2    113785600000
Name: userid, dtype: object
```

---

```
df.userid = df.userid.map(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x))
print (df)
         userid
0           nan
1  109117800000
2  113785600000
```

I wondered whether `map` would be faster, but it is the same:

```
#[300000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (df)

In [40]: %timeit (df.userid.map(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x)))
1 loop, best of 3: 211 ms per loop

In [41]: %timeit (df.userid.apply(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x)))
1 loop, best of 3: 210 ms per loop
```

Another solution is [`to_string`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_string.html), but it is slow:

```
print(df.userid.to_string(float_format='{:.0f}'.format))
0            nan
1   109117800000
2   113785600000

In [41]: (df.userid.to_string(float_format='{:.0f}'.format))
1 loop, best of 3: 2.52 s per loop
```

Comment: though you might want to replace 'nan' back to pd.NA with `replace` after the map.

Answer (score 4):

I just stumbled upon this problem after reading a dataframe from a json file using the `read_json` method and unfortunately it does not have a `keep_default_na` parameter.

The solution was to convert the long floats to `np.int64` before converting them to `str`.

```
In [53]: tweet_id_sample = tweets.iloc[0]['id']
         tweet_id_sample
Out[53]: 8.924206435553362e+17

In [54]: tweet_id_sample.astype(str)
Out[54]: '8.924206435553362e+17'

In [55]: tweet_id_sample.astype(np.int64).astype(str)
Out[55]: '892420643555336192'

In [56]: # This overflows
         tweet_id_sample.astype(int)
Out[56]: -2147483648
```