# Avoid scientific notation for integer numbers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I suppress scientific notation for integer numbers in data frames in Pandas?

I got this:

```
48726528
97573906
7E+07
```

instead of this:

```
48726528
97573906
69857386
```

Comment: if you type: `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` and execute before printing this does it solve?

Comment: or check this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157981/pandas-convert-float-in-scientific-notation-to-string

Comment: @anky_91`np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)`  doesn't work. I got `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'set_printoptions'`

Comment: that is after `import numppy as np` also check the second link

Comment: what is `df.dtypes` or `Series.dtype` (if it's a Series). Are you sure you don't have a `NaN` value somewhere in your column, which is casting it to `float`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to be sure that your values are indeed integers. 
If you wish, you can convert it in integers: 
`df[your_column].astype(int)`

Comment: Are you sure that you wrote: 
`df = df.astype(int)` ? 
The conversion is not made inplace, you need to copy of your DataFrame.

Comment: thank you, I found the cause of the problem, the cause isn't related to `pandas`.