# pandas convert big int to string avoid scientific notation

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe from a csv file that loads with pandas.read_csv() method, looks like:

```
                   id  col
0 1151377158377549824 row0
1 1151346166619103232 row1
2 1151737502769827840 row2
```

types of columns is:

```
df.dtypes
out:
id        float64
col       object
```

i want to chang type of id to string but using astype(str) or apply(str), after convert it changes to scientific notation:

```
                      id  col
0 1.1513771583775498e+18 row0
1 1.1513461666191032e+18 row1
2 1.1517375027698278e+18 row2
```

what should i do to avoid scientific notation after converting?

Comment: The `id` column is not a floating point number, and you should prevent pandas from reading it as such. If you want to have as as a string, use the `dtype` argument to `read_csv` to read it as a an object.

Comment: Your id column dtype is being wrongly inferred as float, as cel says. Use explicit dtype

Comment: maybe i need this columns as float like string, then what?

Comment: python automatically interpret the id column as float so you are getting scientific notation. So while reading the csv specify the data type of column

pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype={'id': 'Int64'})

Above line will solve the problem while reading the df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert to Int64 and then to string:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].astype("Int64").astype(str)
df
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Be careful when having nans as they are replaced by "<NA>". Other solutions are mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157981/pandas-convert-float-in-scientific-notation-to-string